# Trying to escape correctly for a class in beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<span class="mn-person-info__name Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold-dense">
        Marina Silon
      </span>
```

I do this and try to find all every thing on the page that has this span class:

```
spans = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'mn-person-info__name Sans-17px-black-85%\-semibold-dense'})
```

However it does not find anything at all.  Am I escaping the - correctly and is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple test code, everything is OK:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<span class="mn-person-info__name Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold-dense">Marina Silon</span>', 'lxml')
spans = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'mn-person-info__name Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold-dense'})
print spans
# print result
[<span class="mn-person-info__name Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold-dense">Marina Silon</span>]
```